# Stop .css() jquery from continuously running after page resize

Tags: jquery, css

I'm having some issues getting this bit of jquery to work like I want. Basically I want to run animations only on larger screen sizes. Any Ideas?

```
function checkWidth() {
    var animateStop = 1;
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if (windowWidth >= 800) {
        $(window).scroll( $.debounce( 10, true, function() {
            fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (fromTop < 1000 && animateStop === 1){
                $("#logo").css({
                    "top":  (.535 * fromTop) + "px", "transform": "scale(" + (1 - (0.001 * fromTop)) + ")"
                });
            }
        }));
    }
    else {
        animateStop = 0;
    }
}

checkWidth();
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

As you can see, I've attempted to inturrupt the code by changing the fromTop variable but it's still ignoring the rules I've set in place after the first if statement becomes true even once. It's looping somehow and I can't figure it out. I'm pretty new at this.

You can preview the code running live [here](http://wakeyyc.com/new/youth.html)

Comment: Could you use media queries to detect the width and CSS3 transitions to perform the animations?

Comment: If I understood your intention correctly, try declaring the variable animateStop outside the function because it is initialized to 1 every time you call the function, also after that make it 1 inside windowWidth condition.

Comment: dougajmcdonald - The point in me using jquery and not directly using CSS3 transitions was to utilize a consistent value that actually counts up and down on page scroll.

UkatJalal - Thanks, I'm going to try this out later but because of the explanation and the easy implementation below, I went with sdgluck's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to 'unbind' your `scroll` event handler within the `checkWidth` function. You can do this using jQuery's [on](https://api.jquery.com/on/) and [off](https://api.jquery.com/off/) methods. I recommend [namespacing the event](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) so that you don't unattach other handlers you might add to `$(window)` using `on`.

```
function checkWidth() {
    var $window = $(window);
    var windowWidth = $window.width();

    if (windowWidth >= 800) {
        // Use `.on` so we can unbind using `.off`
        // and namespace our event
        $window.on('scroll.animation', $.debounce(10, true, function() {
            fromTop = $window.scrollTop();

            if (fromTop < 1000){
                $("#logo").css({
                    "top":  (.535 * fromTop) + "px",
                    "transform": "scale(" + (1 - (0.001 * fromTop)) + ")"
                });
            }
        }));
    } else {
        $window.off('.animation'); // Unbind previously attached handler
    }
}

checkWidth();
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```